# Autocorrect spelling mistakes

Tags: spell-checking

I've turned on spellcheck with

```
:set spell spelllang=en_us
```

I can now correct the spelling of a word by typing `1z=` (that is, choose the `1`st spelling correction (`z=`)).

How can I make this automatically run on the previous word whenever I type a space, without any delays? It also tries to "fix" words that are *already spelled correctly* (which is why I can't do something like `` inoremap <space> <esc>mmb1z=`ma<space> ``), so I only want to correct every word I type **if it's misspelled**.

Is there any way to autocorrect misspelled words in Vim?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/panozzaj/vim-autocorrect)

Comment: @ArturoVolpe That seems like a legitimate answer to the question.

Comment: could you combine the previous error '[s' in a remap? I would add as an answer but don't know how to do the remap so I'll leave that for someone else.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend against automatically fixing every word that is marked wrong, for two reasons.

- First, you'll get a lot of false positives on things you meant to type, especially in more technical writing.
  You certainly can (and perhaps should) add these two your dictionary so that they're recognized and suggested.
  However, if you don't notice that they're autocorrected, they could slip through to a final version of a document—or worse, if you're writing code or a configuration file (e.g., changing `xmin` to `min` would make the graph look totally wrong).
  Comments can also become weird (e.g., I had "Label and nullary instruction" changed to "Label and nullify instruction," which changes the meaning (a) from a noun phrase to an imperative, and (b) to meaning something completely different.)
- Second, the autocorrect is pretty poor on short words.
  In my experience, it tends to complete to the closest word, which, with, e.g., three-letter words, can be totally different from what you mean.
  If you mean to type *of* but accidentally type *fo*, it will be corrected to *few*—not what you wanted!
  Again, these can be hard to catch in cursory revisions.

With that in mind, I think your *real* goal is to be able to quickly recognize and fix typographical errors.

I use the following mappings to accomplish this:

```
" Go back to last misspelled word and pick first suggestion.
inoremap <C-L> <C-G>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<C-G>u

" Select last misspelled word (typing will edit).
nnoremap <C-K> <Esc>[sve<C-G>
inoremap <C-K> <Esc>[sve<C-G>
snoremap <C-K> <Esc>b[sviw<C-G>
```

When I'm typing body text, any misspelled words will be underlined, per my highlighting settings.
If I see that the word is relatively long and it's a simple typo, then I can figure that `spell` will probably fix it correctly, so I hit `<C-L>` and just keep typing.
If it's a shorter word or I anticipate that it will get it wrong, I can press `<C-K>` and adjust it myself.
Finally, if `spell` unexpectedly corrects to the wrong thing, I've set an undo marker with `<C-G>u`, so I can just `<Esc>ucW` to change it manually
This makes for a very quick workflow most of the time.

Comment: @Rich Please explain why fixing every word is an excellent idea.

Comment: @Rich It may be a positive addition to add an explanation in your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

By chance, I have written a plugin that does exactly this. It is called [Vim You, Autocorrect!](https://github.com/sedm0784/vim-you-autocorrect)

After installing, type `:EnableAutocorrect` to switch it on in any buffer, and you will soon see that [wchargin's scaremongering](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/312/343) is quite unfounded.

Comment: Note your comment on wchargin's answer got flagged as rude, I edited it to remove the "Poppycock!" and dismissed the flag. Not a big deal, just FYI.

Comment: @MartinTournoij It's fine. Lots of people on reddit also [didn't get the joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/8azuun/vim_you_autocorrect/). :) (Thanks for the heads up, though.)

Comment: mr Rich which package i want to install and type :EnableAutoCorrect
i didnt understand

Comment: @MPCreations Do you use a plugin manager?

Comment: @MPCreations Maybe take a look at the answers to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi if you don't know how to install a plugin

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that this is amazing.