# Can I record a macro that accepts the first spelling suggestion?

Tags: macro, spell-checking

I'm trying to [bulk correct some OCR formatting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064538/how-to-separate-erroneously-combined-words-in-ocred-text). I tried recording a macro that would:

1. `]s` (advance to the next spelling error)
2. `z=` (view the suggested corrections)
3. `1` (choose the first suggested correction)

Unfortunately for my purposes, when I replay the macro, it pauses at the step #3 and waits for me to make the selection. Is there a way to still automate that step too (as part of the macro or otherwise)?

Thanks!

Comment: Check help z= it takes a count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a count as @Mass and @D.BenKnoble suggest:

1. `]s`
2. `1z=`

But let's take a closer look at why your original macro was failing, because it's not quite as simple as @Ralf implies.

First try recording your steps into register `"r`:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Then use @Ralf's `:let` command to set up register `"s`

```
:let @s="]sz=1\<cr>"
```

And then take a look at the difference in the output of `:registers`:

```
"r   ]sz=1^M
"s   ]sz=1^M^J
```

When you were recording your macro, you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you can see that it's been included in the `"r` register as a `CTRL-M` or `CR` character. (As you may already know, pressing <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> within a terminal does the same thing, for [historical reasons](https://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html).)

However, when you set the `"s` register directly with the `:let` command, the `\<CR>` carriage return has been included as a `CTRL-M` followed by a `CTRL-J` (`CRLF`). I have no idea why there is a difference or why the `LF` is required for the macro to work, but let's try re-recording the macro and this time pressing <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd> after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see if we can include this character in our recording:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>CTRL-J</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Now let's take another look at the `:registers` output again:

```
"r   ]sz=1^M^@
"s   ]sz=1^M^J
```

Okay. Not quite right: pressing <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd> seems to have inserted a `NUL` character into our macro instead of a `LF`. (Again, [no real idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389839/1208424) why [this is](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#NL-used-for-Nul).) Still, try running the new macro, and you will discover that it works!

**Extra Credit:**

Now let's make the macro recursive so we can [correct](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15872/343) the entire file with a single <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>CTRL-J</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: +1 for the `^@` and `^J`, i wish someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1):

First assign the macro. Lets use register `s`:

```
:let @s="]sz=1\<cr>"
```

The special thing is `\<cr>`. This is Carriage Return that you need to hit after selecting the first spell sugestion.

As Mass &  D. Ben Knoble pointed out, `z=` can take a count. So even simpler:

```
:let @s="]s1z="
```

Now use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to execute the macro in register `s`. For the following invocations just use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.

---

BTW: Be careful with this. I tested it on a text that contains the word "octothorpe". This was detected as spelling error and the first suggestion was "onto Thorpe".

Comment: why not just use `1z=`?

Comment: @Mass thats what i thought when i saw the question.

Comment: @Mass, D.BenKnoble updated. Thanks for the hint.